# Как остановить перезагрузку страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно сделать небольшую консольку, отсылать введённое пользователем должна по нажатию на энтер. Есть такой код

```
$("#consoleForm").keypress(function(event){//<input type="text">
            if(event.keyCode === 13){
                //Остальной код
            }
        });
```

Но при нажатии на энтер страница перезагружается. Как остановить перезагрузку?
P.S. Этот `<input type = "text">` запоминает, что в него вводили и выкидывает подсказку, как её убрать?

Comment: 1. `return false;` 2. `autocomplete="off"`

Answer (score 2):

Избавиться от обработчика `keypress` и использовать `submit`:

```js
var $dest = $("pre"), $src = $("input[type='text']");

$("form").submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $dest.text($dest.text() + "\n" + $src.val());
  $src.val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <pre></pre>
  <input type=text autofocus><input type=submit value=Ok>
</form>
```

Comment: Всё равно перезагружает. Тем более необходима реакция только на Энтер, никаких кнопок.

Comment: @ДимаЛукашов, нет.

Comment: @ДимаЛукашов, т. е. когда ты нажимаешь enter в моём примере, строка не добавляется? Ведь добавляется же.